# Voice/audio distortion in JAVA

Tags: java, android, audio, audio-recording, voice

Wondering if there are any guides/tutorials of how to create a voice/audio distortion software with JAVA.

I would like to have something I could use in Skype/regular phone calls. Maybe something you can implement as an Android app.

Thanks!